# Предупреждение о неинициализированном массиве

Tags: c++, массивы, инициализация, clang++

Как убрать предупреждение о неинициализированном массиве в следующем коде, ведь все элементы инициализированы?

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    constexpr std::size_t size = 1000000;

    std::array<int, size> array;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        array[i] = i / 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ну у вас массив с миллионом неинициализированных значений. вызовите конструктор инициализации всех значений в 0 по дефолту.

Comment: @raviga так это замедлит программу

Comment: а в какой IDE работаете ?

Comment: @raviga `CLion`

Comment: потому что вот смотрю, что VS2019 не ругается. ну тогда инициализация в 0 это скорее ворк-эраунд, так как оно и без того работает как ожидается. можете посмотреть в их документации, как выключить инспектейшены. (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html)

Comment: Нет, у вас ни одного элемента не инициализируется, предупреждение совершенно правильное. Кроме того, такой большой массив с автоматическим хранением может и не прокатить.

Comment: @VTT но потом им же всем присваиваются значения, значит, предупреждать не надо. Почему может не прокатить?

Comment: Потому что такой массив выделяется на стеке, а место в стеке обычно ограничено несколькими мегабайтами.

Comment: А предупреждение бредовое, согласен.

Comment: Потому что между созданием неинициализированных объектов и кодом, который потом присваивает им значения, постоянно наровит пролезть код, пытающийся их использовать. [Cpp Core Guideline: Always initialize an object](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-always)

Comment: Вы точно говорите правду? Например, VC++ предупреждает только о преобразовании `size_t` в `int` в присваивании `array[i] = i / 2;`.

Comment: @Harry В VS анализ включается отдельно и выдает `warning C26494: Variable 'array' is uninitialized. Always initialize an object (type.5).`

Answer (score 0):

В `CLion` это можно сделать так:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma ide diagnostic ignored "cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-member-init"
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    constexpr std::size_t size = 1000000;

    std::array<int, size> array;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        array[i] = i / 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```